# Index Out of Range on accessing List<List<T>> with For loops

Tags: c#

Hobbyist start C# coder here. Think I am missing something basic here. I am trying to create a new List by parsing through a List> using two for loops. I am getting Index Out of Range although from what I can tell in debugging, there is data in the Deal object in the [index][index] location being accessed.

```
            List<List<Deal>> Deals = await Database.LoadRecordsAsync(form, depts);
            for (int dept = 0; dept <= Deals.Count; dept++)
            {
                List<Deal> batch = new List<Deal>();
                for (int deal = Deals[dept].Count; deal >= 0; deal--)
                {
                    batch.Add(Deals[dept][deal]); // Error here
                }
            }
```

Deals in debugging has indexes as expected with data as expected. Am I initializing something incorrectly?

Comment: the condition --> `dept <= Deals.Count` is one of the issues. then you've got `int deal = Deals[dept].Count` which should be `int deal = Deals[dept].Count - 1`

Comment: `Deals.Count` is the number of elements, in a zero-based array. Meaning that your first element is really `[0]` not `[1]`, therefore you can't go until `dept <= Deals.Count` because the last index is actually `Deals.Count - 1`, so you should have `dept < Deals.Count` instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the following line:

```
deal = Deals[dept].Count
```

This line should change as below:

```
deal = Deals[dept].Count - 1
```

**as well** the upper bound of the first for. The following

```
dept <= Deals.Count
```

should change as below:

```
dept < Deals.Count
```

Generally speaking, if you declare an array of n items the last item of the array can be accessed by using the index `n-1`.

That being said if you declare `deal` as `Deals[dept].Count` and later on you attempt to read this:

```
Deals[dept][deal]
```

you are out of the range of the array you have defined.

Comment: Also `dept <= Deals.Count` in the first for loop

Comment: Green check! Thank you, what a bone headed mistake. A bit embarrassing how long I spent before asking here also.
Now sure why my question gets downvoted. I don't think I understand this place. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: @ZoomStop You are welcome. I am glad that I helped. Unfortunately, some users downvote without leaving any comment let alone any constructive comment.